# How to show (as output cell) the contents of a .py file with syntax highlighting?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm aware of the `%load` function (formerly `%loadpy`) which loads the contents of a file (or URL, ...) into a new input cell (which can be executed afterwards).

I'm also aware of `%less`, `%more` and `%pycat`, which show the contents of a file in a *pager* (which means in the notebook it's shown in the split-window at the bottom of the screen).

Is there a (magic) command to load a file and show its content (with syntax highlighting) in an output cell?

I.e. something like the following but with syntax highlighting of the result:

```
with open('my_file.py', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

I want the file content to be stored with the .ipynb file but I don't want it to be executed when I do *Cell -> Run All*.

Is there a command similar to `%psource` which shows the source code in an output cell instead of a *pager*?

Comment: For the record, I've just seen that there has been a Gist for that all along: https://gist.github.com/jiffyclub/5385501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not way to do that with current magics, but it is pretty easy using [pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/) and returning `IPython.display.HTML(...)`.

Answer (score 21):

Example code based on answer by @Matt:

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
import IPython

with open('my_file.py') as f:
    code = f.read()

formatter = HtmlFormatter()
IPython.display.HTML('<style type="text/css">{}</style>{}'.format(
    formatter.get_style_defs('.highlight'),
    highlight(code, PythonLexer(), formatter)))
```

Answer (score 7):

10 years later, and there's now a much simpler solution:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Code

```py
from IPython.display import Code

Code(filename='my_file.py', language='python')
```