# iPython Notebook - Display source code for bash script with syntax highlighting

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-notebook

#### How can I display contents of bash script with syntax highlighting in iPython notebook?

My workflow usually consists of calling different bash scripts, and I would like to document the source code for these scripts in my notebook. My current solution is to make a bash cell and `cat` the script to have its contents display in the cell output. However, the script is not formatted and this is a bit cumbersome as well.

#### Example:

Code cell:

```
%%bash
cat myScript.sh
```

Output:

`#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..3}; do [ "$i" == "2" ] && echo "This is my bash script"; done`

Desired output (with syntax highlighting):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..3}; do [ "$i" == "2" ] && echo "This is my bash script"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pygments in a [similar fashion to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665118/how-to-show-source-code-of-a-package-function-in-ipython-notebook). Here's an example:

```
def highlight_source_bash(filename):
    """For use inside an IPython notebook: given a filename, print the source code. Bash version."""

    from pygments import highlight
    from pygments.lexers import BashLexer
    from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
    from IPython.core.display import HTML

    with open (filename, "r") as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()

    return HTML(highlight(data, BashLexer(), HtmlFormatter(full=True)))
```

Then calling `highlight_source_bash('myScript.sh')` should give the desired output.